# How to change image src when parent has "selected" class?

Tags: javascript, dom

Im trying to change the image by looking at the parent class to see if it has "selected" in it. I have some code that adds the "selected" class to the "platform-selection" class.

```html
<div class="platform-selection selected">
    <div style="margin: 5px;">
        <img src="xbox1.png" id="xbox" />
     </div>
</div>
```

```
    var xboxselected = document.getElementById("xbox").parentElement.parentElement.classList;
    if(xboxselected = "selected")
        {
           document.getElementById("xbox").src="xbox2.png";
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById("xbox").src="xbox1.png";
        }
```

I want to change the image to xbox2.png only when its parent parent has "selected" class. I instantly get the xbox2.png

Comment: You could probably do all of this without JavaScript by using CSS selectors and an invisible image or a fixed-size placeholder with a background image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(xboxselected = "selected")
```

That should be

```
if (xboxselected.contains("selected"))
```

`=` is assignment, not comparison. To compare things for equality you'd use `===` (or `==`), but that makes no sense here because `xboxselected` is not a string, but a [class list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

Just use its `.contains` method.

---

That said, if all you want to do is show a different picture depending on the class of a parent element (and the picture should change "live" whenever the class changes), you can just use CSS:

```js
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function () {
    document.querySelector('.platform-selection').classList.toggle('selected');
};
```

```css
.platform-selection img.alternative {
    display: none;
}

.platform-selection.selected img {
    display: none;
}

.platform-selection.selected img.alternative {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="platform-selection">
    <div style="margin: 5px;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/1aCFcDj.jpg">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rmPqh.gif" class="alternative">
     </div>
</div>

<button id="demo">Toggle selection</button>
```

There are two images. We use CSS to hide one of them initially (the one with class `alternative`). Whenever the parent element gains the `selected` class (here provided by a toggle button), it hides the (normally visible) contained image and displays the (normally hidden) `alternative` image.

Comment: It works when I add the "selected" class and I it only works once at the start. Do I need a loop or something for it to work?

Comment: @hexer34 Depends on when you want to do the check. Why do you have code that adds `selected` at all? Why not just change the image?

Comment: I have two more of these divs with "platform-selection" and when I click on the first one the it deletes the "selected" class from the other. I have a transform attribute in the css for the scale to animate it when I select it.

Comment: @hexer34 That sounds like the sort of thing you can do completely without JavaScript. You'd probably just need some sort of radio button that gets restyled with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xboxselected = document.getElementById("xbox").parentElement.parentElement.classList;
```

This will return an Array of classes. You need to check if `selected` exists in the ClassList or not.

```
if(xboxselected.value.indexOf("selected") > -1){

   document.getElementById("xbox").src="xbox2.png";

 } else {

   document.getElementById("xbox").src="xbox1.png";

  }`
```

Comment: No, it returns a live [`DOMTokenList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList), which is not the same as an array.

Comment: Oh. Yes, it's a ClassList not an array.